# Pass a vector by reference C++

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I can't figure out why this won't work?
I need to pass the vector reference so I can manipulate it from an external function.

There are several questions on this on the internet but I can't understand the replies?

code below:.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

string funct(vector<string> *vec)
{
    cout << vec[1] << endl;

}



int main()
{

vector<string> v;
v.push_back("one");
v.push_back("two");
v.push_back("three");


}
```

Comment: `vector<string> *vec` means passing by pointer, change it to `vector<string> &vec` if you want passing by reference.

Comment: I don't see you passing any vectors. By reference or value.

Comment: Good question.. Poorly addressed across the web. Good answer below but it doesn't address pointers when passing vectors as function arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly you need to learn the differences between references and pointers and then the difference between `pass-by-reference` and `pass-by-pointer`.

A function prototype of the form:

```
void example(int *);  //This is pass-by-pointer
```

expects a function call of the type:

```
int a;         //The variable a
example(&a);   //Passing the address of the variable
```

Whereas, a prototype of the form:

```
void example(int &);  //This is pass-by-reference
```

expects a function call of the type:

```
int a;       //The variable a
example(a);
```

Using the same logic, if you wish to pass the vector by reference, use the following:

```
void funct(vector<string> &vec)  //Function declaration and definition
{
//do something
}

int main()
{
vector<string> v;
funct(v);            //Function call
}
```

EDIT: A link to a basic explanation regarding pointers and references:

https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~patrick/csc418/wi2004/notes/PointersVsRef.pdf